# Why are some of my request parameters sent as `null` to my controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm developing a LiveWire/Laravel project and in my `product.blade.php`, the `category_id` is sent as `null` to the `store` function. Apparently there is no problem in my input and my model and `category_id` is defineded in my `component`.

I used some artisan comands related to clearing the cache and config and even I created another component with different name but I met same bug

dd:

```
array:8 [▼
  "title" => "تراکت"
  "en_title" => "tracket"
  "category_id" => null
  "description" => "nothing"
  "status" => 1
  "img" => null
  "price" => "48000"
  "keywords" => "tracket"
]
```

Livewire Product Blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">دسته بندی محصول</label>
    <select wire:model="category_id" id="select-countries" class="form-control custom-select">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
            @if(count($category->childrenRecursive) >0)
                @include('Admin.category.partials',['categories'=>$category->childrenRecursive,'level'=>1,'create'=>1])
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Livewire Component :

```
<?php

class Index extends Component
{
    public $title,$en_title,$category_id,$description,$status=1,$img=null,$price,$keywords;

    public function store(){
       
      $keywords=serialize(explode(",",$this->keywords));
      Product::create([
         'title'=>$this->title,
         'en_title'=>$this->en_title,
         'category_id'=>$this->category_id,
         'description'=>$this->description,
         'status'=>$this->status,
         'price'=>$this->price,
         'image'=>$this->img,
          'keywords'=>$keywords,
      ]);
        $this->reset(['title','en_title','category_id','description','price']);

      session()->flash('add_product','محصول شما با موفقیت اضافه شد');


    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories=Category::with('childrenRecursive')->where('parent_id',null)->get();
        $products=Product::latest()->paginate(8);
        return view('livewire.admin.product.index',compact('categories','products'))->extends('layouts.admin')->section('content');
    }
}
```

Comment: ```Controller``` and ```Component``` are different things. Where do you use ```dd```? If I were you, I would use default CRUD for this task.

Comment: but this way work for me in other items like  my orders and my categories and i use dd in my store function in controller @Hopex Developmen

Comment: For correctly creating, you need to add before create your item fields validation. And ```category_id``` isn't initialize before sending to view component. Sorry if I misunderstood your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax appears correct and I suspect you're sometimes seeing `null` because you're not setting an initial value for `$category_id`. Therefore, if you don't select an `option` from your `select` element and submit your form, the value of `$category_id` will be `null`.

You can perform some `component` initialization in the `mount` method where I suggest you set an initial value for your public properties:

```
public $categories, $products;
public $category_id;

public function mount()
{
    $this->categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')
        ->where('parent_id', null)
        ->get();
    $this->products = Product::latest()->paginate(8);

    $this->category_id = $this->categories->first()->id;
}

public function render()
{
    return view(
        'livewire.admin.product.index',
        compact('categories','products')
    )
    ->extends('layouts.admin')
    ->section('content');
}
```